# How would you allow non-privileged users to excute files that have 774 permissions?

Tags: linux

How would you allow non-privileged users to execute files that have 774 permissions?

Comment: I had to issue a down vote on this question because the question changed, I am considering, rolling the question back myself but decided just to flag it for moderator review.  Its not acceptable to post a question, get an answer to that question, then change the entire question to something else.  Its extremely suspicious and you won't get reputation if you do that.

Comment: I've rolled it back. We have the edit ability for that very reason.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, please use the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) link.

Comment: Welcome to superuser - While your posts are your own, its *very* bad form to move the goalposts, or in this case randomly turn a game of cricket into full contact rugby. I'd strongly encourage that edits *refine* questions, and discourage completely changing the question

Answer (score 3):

You can add them to the group that owns the file. Make sure it's executable.

```
// Add user to group
usermod -a -G groupName userName
// Create a group if you like
groupadd groupName
// Change group ownership of exe
chown [user]:[group] /path/to/exe
// Make exe exe-utable
chmod +x /path/to/exe
```

Enjoy

Comment: how can i talk you in chat?

Comment: @FuLe - You don't.  You require at least 25 reputation points in order to do that and only if the other person is willing to talk to in a chat room.

Comment: @alex: If you do a chmod +x then it's not 774 anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an entry in /etc/sudoers to allow just that person (or some select group of users) to execute just that command not as root but as the owner of that specific file or as a dummy user who belongs to the group for that file.